# cant find windows driver option under visual c++ in visual studio (WDK is installed)

Tags: visual-studio, kernel, driver, wdk

i have already installed WDK. Any help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlHg8.png)

Comment: Some versions of WDK don't have plugins for certain versions of Visual Studio. Until recently, the latest WDK didn't have a plugin for VS2017. 
What version of both do you have?

Comment: Did you install WDK before Visual Studio? If so, I believe that you have to install Visual Studio first, then the WDK.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2017.
2. Install Windows 10 SDK.
3. Install Windows Driver Kit (WDK) for your version of Visual Studio (there's a new version recently released for VS17).

Then you should be good to go. I've done this over and over repeatedly for a number of systems/new environments before, never ever encountered an issue when following this pattern.

I do not recommend having both Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 installed at the same time, or multiple SDK versions though. I've seen way too many conflicts due to this in the past.